# Want to know who is login Admin/User

Tags: admin, users, login, dashboard

want to know who is login in my wordpress website if admin login then go to dashboard and if user login then go to homepage

Approach:
I used this code

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

   echo ‘ user is loin ‘ ;

} else {

 echo ‘ Not Login ‘ ;

} ?>
```

and

```
if(is_admin()) { ...output my admin stuff....}
```

but doesn't work. any help would be extremely appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

is_admin() only checkes if the dashboard page is displayed or not, if you want to tell the role of a user, try [current_user_can( $capability )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can)

Comment: i used this but its not working.
`if(current_user_can('admin')){
 echo 'The current user is an admin';
}
if(current_user_can('subscriber')){
 echo 'The current user is an subscriber';
}`

Comment: i applied in header.php file so is that a right file to insert that code?

Comment: @jassi9911 The default admin role is called "administrator", not "admin". Try current_user_can('administrator').

Comment: just find this
Do not pass a role name to current_user_can(), as this is not guaranteed to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

ok finally i solved my own problem here is the solution

```
get_currentuserinfo() ;
if ($user_level > 0) { // if admin login
    echo "admin login";
} else {
    echo "user login";
}
```

Comment: User levels are deprecated, use `current_user_can()` with [appropriate role or capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities) instead.

Comment: `current_user_can()` i used it and its not working:(

Comment: Downvote: user levels are deprecated. Don't use this solution.